# WoeUSB gives status 256

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows-10, woeusb

I tried to create a Windows 10 USB boot medium with WoeUSB. I formatted a USB drive with an NTFS partition, but WoeUSB complains with:

```
Installation failed!  
Exit code: 256   
Log:  
WoeUSB v@@WOEUSB_VERSION@@
============================== 
Mounting source filesystem...  
Wiping all existing partition table and filesystem signatures in /dev/sdc... wipefs:
error: /dev/sdc: probing initialization failed The command "wipefs --all 
"${target_device}"" failed with exit status "1", program is prematurely aborted   
Unmounting and removing "/medi/woeusb_source_1530017199_18199"...  
You may now safely detach the target device
```

or

```
 wipefs: WARNING: /dev/sdc: appears to contain 'dos' partition table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start wousb from command line:

```
sudo woeusb --partition Win10_1803_EnglishInternational_x64.iso /dev/sdc1
```

Comment: Reading at https://askubuntu.com/questions/561853  about similar issues I found that calling the tool via command line leads to the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

dont eject just unmount.

this is what worked:

1. insert usb stick
2. open gparted
3. unmount using gparted
4. format to ntfs using gparted
5. close gparted
6. Use woeusb, it should work now

Comment: I tried ejecting many times before I found this.  This worked:

1. insert usb stick

2. umount /dev/sdb1

3. Use woeusb (just click Install again)

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo wipefs --all --force /dev/sdX
```

You'll need to change `/dev/sdX` to your device

Comment: Thanks this worked

Answer (score 0):

Below steps worked for me for windows 7 bootable pendrive in ubuntu-18.04

Step 1: Download the latest bash file from the release of the WoeUSB page https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB/releases

Step 2: Fix the missing executable file permission chmod +x path/to/woeusb-N.N.N.bash

Step 3: Install GParted sudo apt-get install gparted

Step 4: Start gparted ui interface

Step 5: Select your drive by top-right dropdown
delete your whole partition using GParted ( Don't create a new partition after that )

Step 6: Make bootable Pendrive ( sudo ./woeusb-N.N.N.bash --target-filesystem NTFS --device path/to/windows.iso /dev/sdX )

```
 wget https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB/releases
 
 sudo apt install gparted
 cp /home/devops/Downloads/woeusb-5.2.4.bash .
 
 
 chmod 777 woeusb-5.2.4.bash 
 sudo ./woeusb-5.2.4.bash  --target-filesystem NTFS --device /home/devops/Downloads/test/en_windows_7_ultimate_x64_dvd.iso  /dev/sdb
  
   sudo apt install wimtools

 # Install above package if you get below error and then rerun woeusb command  below it again
 
 # "error woeusb requires wimlib-imagex command in the executable search path, but it is not found"

   sudo ./woeusb-5.2.4.bash  --target-filesystem NTFS --device /home/devops/Downloads/test/en_windows_7_ultimate_x64_dvd.iso  /dev/sdb
```